# A big tuck sound from the back

Tags: noise, mazda

My car is doing great but now suddenly I hear this big tuk sound from the back as if something has misplaced. It happens repeatedly with intervals. I examined my car underneath and I blame this one join which seem to be out of place. I am attaching photos. The car is Mazda 626, year 2000.
[image: The join clearly is out of its place. I dont know what it is]

Here is a picture of the read left (the same thing) which *is* in place.

[image: Rear left which is in place]

Can someone tell me what this is? Is the car ok to drive to mechanic (5 miles)? Can I fix it myself? How much would it cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's looks like the links between the frame and stabilizer bar. I've change mine recently (on a Toyota Land Cruiser) because the bushing where in terrible shape. Change both side while you are there, 4 bolts total.

This is [from NAPA](http://napaonline.com/Catalog/CatalogItemDetail.aspx?A=ATM1031307_0257628974&An=599001%20102000%2050042%202042012%2025007&Ar=AND%28P_RecType:A%29) (Sway Bar Link - Rear Susp) for a 2000 Mazda 626 for ~35$/each:

[image: Sway Bar Link - Rear Susp]

Comment: Thank you. I think I can't change it myself, can I? Do you know the the big Tuck sound could be produce by this?

Comment: I have no idea what a "tuck" sound is, but broken end links will let the swaybar flop around and make sounds like the whole car is falling apart.  :-)

Comment: @Dave I think you can do it yourself, only 4 bolts to remove and 4 to replace. If you are unsure, see a professional!

Comment: checked this video on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OReNlwP8xRY. While it really looks easy for Mazda, the guy had to break off one bolt. I guess better to get it done by someone else.

Comment: @Dave yes, and they will usually guarantee the job done. Good luck!